# Beautiful soup: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to extract the first 16 **bold sentences** via this [website](https://www.nairaland.com/2838393/owe-ile-yoruba-some-lovely) before inserting them into a dataframe, and i kept having this error. I have tried everything i could, also i'm a beginner in webscraping.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.nairaland.com/2838393/owe-ile-yoruba-some-lovely')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html')

yoruba = []
for word in soup3.findAll('b'):
    name = word.find('i')
    yoruba.append(name.text)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-9d3379b8790a> in <module>
      7 for word in soup3.findAll('b'):
      8     name = word.find('i')
----> 9     yoruba1.append(name.text)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
```

Comment: The error tells you exactly what is wrong.  `name`, on line 9, is `None`.  `None` doesn't have a `text` member.  You have to handle the case where your `find` fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res = requests.get('https://www.nairaland.com/2838393/owe-ile-yoruba-some-lovely')
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content,'html.parser')

yoruba = []
for word in soup.findAll('b'):
    name = word.find('i')
    if name:
        yoruba.append(name.text)

print(set(yoruba))
```

output:

> {'Atari ajanaku kii seru omode', 'Igi gogoro ma gun mi loju, lati
>   okere laati wo', 'Enibama ba esu jeun sibi e a gun', "Ori leja fi
>   l'abu ja", 'Aseju ni irun aya, irun abe tito', 'Ki tan lara were koma
>   ku "HOI"', 'Foriti foriti lomu ki ori agba pa', 'Omi titun ti ru, eja
>   titun ti wonu e', "Eni bama m'obo akoko se bi lagido", "Pai lotun pai
>   losi, t'oju o ba fo, a ko ma wo bai bai ni", "Ejawo ninu apon tio yo,
>   elogbomi'ila kana", "Ninu odo adagun ni alakan ti le fo epo, t'odo ba
>   di agadangba, a gbe alakan lo", 'Igi gogoro ma gun mi loju, lati okere
>   laati ye', 'Aje ke lana omo ku loni, tani o sai mope aje ana lo pa omo
>   je', "Isiro l'oko dido", 'Oro yi so simi lenu o buyo si. Iso o se
>   ponla, iyo o se tu danu', 'Moja mosa laa mo akinkanju loju ogun'}